# Why should we not include business logic in database triggers?

Tags: sql, database, triggers

The business side of my company would like to implement 20 new triggers with very specific business logic. They are also constantly coming back with changes to old triggers. The logic is just group structure depending on parameters 99% of the time.

I have tried time and time again to stop this, but they are used to this process now and expect it. If I disagree, I am told that I still have to implement these.

I need to outline to them in non-technical terms that they will understand why we should not implement these triggers and move these tasks to be developed within our application.

So far I have told them:

1. Severely high risk of data being lost/overwritten
2. High DB cost in $
3. Unnecessary work that could be automated via the application

Are there any other items that could be added to this list?

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Thanks!

1. Severely high risk of data being lost/overwritten
2. High DB cost in $
3. Unnecessary work that could be automated via the application

Comment: QA is usually easier on code than on the db

Answer (score 4):

The three reasons you gave are wrong, and betray a pure coder perspective :

1. Severely high risk of data being lost/overwritten

   (you don't have that risk if your stuff is to be coded in a language that just happens not to be named SQL ?)
2. High DB cost in $

   (you don't have that risk if your stuff is to be coded in a language that just happens not to be named SQL ?)
3. Unnecessary work that could be automated via the application

   (Automating your stuff in a language that just happens not to be named SQL is not a process that involves doing analysis and writing implementation code ?)

Triggers are a useful construct for at least one purpose : for guarding data integrity with respect to all integrity rules that aren't supported by SQL declaratively. See "Advanced Mathematics for Database Professionals", chpt 11 for extensive detail.

All that said : designers should beware of attaching [execution of] code to, say, INSERT INTO CUSTOMER for reasons of, say "that happens only if we register a new customer, and all new customers should be getting a welcome letter (or some such)". Consider you taking over another company and all its customers are to be integrated in your database. Ouch. Ill-inspired uses of triggers can often be traced down to "attaching business meaning too eagerly to a db operation happening". This particular stuff indeed does belong in the part where the "business transaction/business function" is coded, which may be application code, or which may be a callable stored procedure (which is distinct from triggers).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. 

1. Yes this is coded in SQL, however this is always a chance that one trigger can impact another, or a new software implementation can be negatively impacted by a trigger. 

2. We need to increase DTU's to keep the same DB performance. This is due to every time data is added to a table with a trigger it has to query to DB for certain logic. 

3. If a feature was implemented within our software that could take care of group structure on scenarios, 99% of triggers would be eliminated.

Comment: I do understand when triggers should be used, however, I do not agree that they should be used under very specific business logic that could be covered in the corresponding application.

Comment: ***All*** logic "could be covered in the application".  That makes that characteristic a non-distinguishing criterion.  And it's not a valid reason for doing it.  In fact it's the *wrong* place for putting data integrity logic in particular (and data integrity logic is indeed a form of business logic).  I don't know what your "scenario's" or "group structures" are, let alone what it means to "take care of them" so I can't sensibly comment any further.

Comment: Additional point : how come it be the "business side" that apparently gets to ***decide*** on matters that are fairly clearly ***technical implementation side*** ???

Answer (score 2):

I *really* dislike triggers for business logic, so this may be more of a rant than an answer...

1. Triggers create a risk of performance problems and locking. There's nothing to stop you from writing triggers with horrible performance characteristics, or even more entertainingly triggers which trigger other triggers which trigger the original trigger.
2. Triggers are "side effects", and for most humans, side effects often lead to bugs. For instance, if someone is working on the code for persisting a new business entity, and that code causes a trigger to fire, they may not consider that in their code and thus cause a bug.

If your answer is "well, don't do those things":

3. Triggers are really hard to test. You have to test every single path that could possibly cause the trigger to fire, and on non-trivial applications, that's usually impossible.

Comment: Thank you, I will add these to my list.

Comment: 1. does not constitute a difference with having the very same process coded as part of the application, so that's not an argument.   2. is incorrect : triggers create side effects only if updates are done from within them.  The argument against side effects is warranted, but the conclusion to avoid triggers altogether is not.  "Advanced Mathematics for Database Professionals" (De Haan/Koppelaars) shows in minute detail the perfectly legitimate case for using triggers.   3. is wrong for the same reasons as 1. : moving this to appl code won't solve the testing problem.

Comment: I agree with you if your argument is "use triggers for data integrity", but the question was about using triggers for business logic. I've updated my answer to explicitly include that caveat.